# Negative Squared Root on Quadratic Equation formula?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

I have this basic problem:

> In a farm, $X$ animals are added to the farm. These animals gain weight according to the equation: $500 - 2X$ gr. Which interval of animals can the farm take, if the total weight gain is greater than $30,600$ Kg?

Original (Spanish - Español):

> En un criadero de cuyes se integran $x$ cuyes, si se tiene presente que los cuyes ganan peso en promedio de $(500 - 2x)$ gramos. ¿Qué intervalo de cuyes puede aceptar esta granja si la ganancia total de peso de los cuyes es mayor a $30 600$ Kg?

Step 1:

Total animals: $x$.

Weigthgain = $(500 - 2x)$ gr.

TotalWeightgain > $30 600(1000)$ converting kg to gr.

Step 2:

$$x(500 - 2x) > 30600000$$

Step 3:

$$0 > 2x^2 - 500x + 30 600 000$$

Step 4:

$$ x = \frac{-(-500) +- \sqrt[2]{(-500)^2 - 4(2)(30 600 000)}}{2(2)}$$

But as you can see, the sqrt is negative. So It does not exist. 
What should be the next step?

Comment: *In a farm, X animals are integrated* - Well, $\displaystyle\int x~dx~=~\dfrac{x^2}2$

Comment: @Lucian, don't get what you say. Please, expand your comment.

Comment: @Lucian is being sarcastic. While amusing, it is not relevant.

Comment: I am curious, though, what do you mean by "integrated"? What doe you mean by "can take the farm"? It's a bit hard to tell what you're asking.

Comment: @Cameron Buie. I think a better translation for those are: 1) are joined? 2) can be put into the farm?. Sorry spanish mother tongue here. I've added the original problem in spanish, in case you know un poco de español.

Comment: Mi vocabulario español es insuficiente. ;-) I have added the `translation-request` tag. Hopefully, one of our users who is fluent in both languages will be able to provide a clear translation.

Comment: @CameronBuie, thanks. Hopefully someone can help.

Comment: I'm a native spanish speaker and I don't get what that means either. @user3352567 Por "integran" te referis a "En un criadero se encuentran"? De todas formas, este termino no parece importar en el ejercicio, haha.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD, I think it refers to the fact that $x$ animals(cuys) are added to the farm. But there is not information on how many were there already, if any.

Comment: Ahh, recien lo entiendo, una traduccion mas adecuada seria "are added to the farm".

Maybe the wrong part is the "Total animals: $x$", as that is only the amount of animals you've added. If you think (I think the question is a bit unclear) the farm was not empty before adding the cuyes, you'd have $x+c_0$ total animals, where $c_0$ denotes the initial amount of cuyes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you've transcribed and translated the question correctly, then your math is correct, and indeed no solution exists. So the next step would be to state that it is impossible for the farm to satisfy these conditions (there is no interval, or an empty interval, of solutions).

However, I suspect that there's an error in the units; likely they were intended to be the same (not grams in one place, kg in another). If we graph $y = x(500 - 2x)$, then we see that the maximum point occurs at (125, 31,250). While that's below 30,600,000 by some 3 orders of magnitude, it is slightly above 30,600, and so you will have a nonempty solution interval if the requirements were in matching units. So that's likely what was intended.

(Another slight correction to what you wrote is that $x$ isn't the total animals on the farm, it's just the added animals. I'm assuming that only these added animals gain weight, not the ones originally present, which are an unknown quantity.)